# Does swagger support the JAX-RS @BeanParam annotation?

Tags: swagger

I'd like to place all the @QueryParams inside a @BeanParam object and further document there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

currently not supported, but you could open a ticket [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues) to see if it can be added

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket related and provided a patch. However the patch is based on the opener's private swagger branch. The change is very simple so it's easy to make a patch.

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/532

Answer (score 1):

According to change log this feature was added in 1.3.5 version.

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Changelog#v135---apr-28-2014

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that this works with Jersey2 and swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10. Just remember to annotate the properties in the @BeanParam target class.